# Generate a matrix of dependencies between elements

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, data-science

I have to build a matrix of dependencies between elements of Data Frame. Each elements in column 's' has a list of different nodes (from 1 to 70) and corresponding time(column 't'). The task is to find all the dependencies between all nodes and put into table the sum of time values.

For example:
node sa1 has connections with following nodes: sa2, sa3(0 line), sa3(1 line), sa5, sa9(3 line)

For nodes sa2, sa5, sa9 with can use a value directly from column 't', because they are present only once. Node 3 is present in two lines, so we add the 't' values.

I have tried to solve it with many for loops, and I have timing problem, to process the data it took around 50 minutes, so need for some hints how to prepare data for analysis.

As I have just noticed, it it necessary to calculate only the elements above of the main diagonal, main diagonal will be NaN, and elements below main diagonal are just mirrored.

This is how example of my input looks like

```
         s           t 

 0  sa1,sa2,sa3     10
 1  sa1,sa3         20
 2  sa1,sa5,sa9     123
```

This is a code to generate the above shown table

```
sas = pd.Series(['sa1,sa2,sa3', 'sa1,sa3', 'sa1,sa5,sa9'], name='s')
times = pd.Series([10, 20, 123], name='t')
df = pd.concat([sas, times], axis=1)
```

I expect to get following table

```
    sa1    sa2    sa3    sa4    sa5    ...    sa9  
sa1  -     10      30           123           123
sa2  10     -
sa3  30              - 
sa4                       -
sa5 123                          -
...                                     -
sa9 123                                        -
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy to achieve by using `dot`

```
s=df.s.str.get_dummies(',')
s=s.mul(df.t,0).T.dot(s)
s.values[[np.arange(s.shape[0])]*2] = 0
s
Out[104]: 
     sa1  sa2  sa3  sa5  sa9
sa1    0   10   30  123  123
sa2   10    0   10    0    0
sa3   30   10    0    0    0
sa5  123    0    0    0  123
sa9  123    0    0  123    0
```

Comment: I would be very thankful if you add some comments to your brilliant solution, I want to learn not only to copy-paste, Thanks!

Comment: @AndreyMazur this is more like matrix multiple , in pandas when you have the same key and columns it will multiple it together

Comment: @AndreyMazur when you have the dummy variable we have the value as columns and index same as original data frame then after transpose we can multiple two matrix get the expected result